# How to insert multiple records within foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert multiple records within foreach loop and it really drives me crazy since it only inserts the first record then stops. Can you help me know where my problem is?

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm) {
    //set variables to use in content below
    $product_name  = $cart_itm["product_name"];
    $product_qty   = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
    $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
    $product_code  = $cart_itm["product_code"];
    //$product_color = $cart_itm["product_color"];
    $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty); //calculate Price x Qty

    $result = "insert into ordered (product_name, product_price) values ('$product_name',$product_price)";
    if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $result)) {
       echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    $bg_color = ($b++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even'; //class for zebra stripe 
    echo '<tr class="'.$bg_color.'">';
    echo '<td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$product_price.'RY</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$subtotal.'RY</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $total = ($total + $subtotal); //add subtotal to total var
}
```

Comment: add `IGNORE` after `INSERT` does that make any difference?

Comment: What is the table structure? Do you have a Primary key? Have you checked the error log?

Comment: thanks, yes I had a primary key which wasn't really useful in this case so i removed it & that helped! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this. This will insert all your data with single query.

```
<?php
$queryData = [];
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
{
    //set variables to use in content below
    $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
    $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
    $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
    $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
    //$product_color = $cart_itm["product_color"];
    $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty); //calculate Price x Qty

    $queryData[] = "('$product_name',$product_price)";
    $bg_color = ($b++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even'; //class for zebra stripe 
    echo '<tr class="'.$bg_color.'">';
    echo '<td><input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$product_price.'RY</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$subtotal.'RY</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $total = ($total + $subtotal); //add subtotal to total var
}

$result="insert into ordered (product_name,product_price) values ".implode(",",$queryData)) . ";";
if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $result)) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
}
```

Comment: I can't see my reply, so I will say thanks again. It worked :)